# json_encde throwing me error

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello guys I have a my front end in ionic and backend in php. Right now I'm trying to send some data back to my angular application but I'm facing some error. I have tried to find the solution but I'm unable to find the solution. please help me in solving this issue thanks. The error that I'm getting is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 331
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (http://192.168.10.5:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14655:14)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://192.168.10.5:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23675:16)
    at http://192.168.10.5:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23766:12
    at forEach (http://192.168.10.5:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13691:20)
    at transformData (http://192.168.10.5:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23765:3)
    at transformResponse (http://192.168.10.5:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24554:21)
    at processQueue (http://192.168.10.5:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29127:28)
    at http://192.168.10.5:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29143:27
    at Scope.$eval (http://192.168.10.5:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30395:28)
```

The part which is of our concern is this :

```
 if($request->category == "key"){
          error_log("in key");
          $key_action = $this->Battleplan_Util->getKeyBattleplan($param["for"]);
          $key_action_count = count($key_action);
          if ($key_action_count == 0){
            error_log("adding");
            $this->addActionInBattleplan($param);
          }else{
            error_log("error found in key");
            $data["status"] = "false";
            $data["type"] = "key";
            $data["data"] = $key_action;
            error_log("Data is : ". print_r($data , true));
            // echo json_encode(array("status"=>"false","type"=>"key","data"=>$key_action[0]));
            echo json_encode(array("data" => $data));
          }
```

My php controller function from where I'm sending data back to my angular view is this:

```
public function addBattleplan(){

    // error_log("Hwllo world");
    // die;
     // $param = $this->input->post();


    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
      $request = json_decode($postdata);
      $token = $request->token;
      $referrer = $request->referrer;
      // $type = $request->type;
      $param["plan"] = $request->plan;
      $param["date"] = $request->date;
      $param["category"] = $request->category;
      $token = $this->common_util->Decrypt('XXXXXXX',$token);


      $user = $this->User_Util->get_token($token);
      if (!$user) {
        echo false;
      }

      $user_id = $user[0]['user_id'];
      if ($request->target) {
          $param['target'] = date('M d, Y' , strtotime($request->target));
        } else {
          $param['target'] = '--';
        }
      // $param['date'] = $this->getToday();
      $param['date'] = date('M d, Y');
      $param['starred'] = FALSE;
      $param['archived'] = FALSE;
      $param["for"] = new MongoId($user_id);
      $param["type"] = "daily";

      error_log("The category is: ". $this->category);
      if ($request->category == "additional"){
        error_log("in additional");
        $this->addActionInBattleplan($param);
      }
      else{

        if($request->category == "key"){
          error_log("in key");
          $key_action = $this->Battleplan_Util->getKeyBattleplan($param["for"]);
          $key_action_count = count($key_action);
          if ($key_action_count == 0){
            error_log("adding");
            $this->addActionInBattleplan($param);
          }else{
            error_log("error found in key");
            $data["status"] = "false";
            $data["type"] = "key";
            $data["data"] = $key_action;
            error_log("Data is : ". print_r($data , true));
            // echo json_encode(array("status"=>"false","type"=>"key","data"=>$key_action[0]));
            echo json_encode(array("data" => $data));
          }
        }else{
          error_log("in important");
          $imp_action = $this->Battleplan_Util->getImportantBattleplan($param["for"]);
          $imp_actions_count = count($imp_action);
          if($imp_actions_count < 5){
            $this->addActionInBattleplan($param);
          }else{
            echo json_encode(array("status"=>"false" , "type"=> "important" , "data"=>$imp_action));
          }
        }
      }

      echo json_encode(array("status" => "true"));
      return;

      // $id = $this->Battleplan_Util->addBattleplan($param);
      // if($id)
      // {

      //   // $c_id = $this->calendar_util->insertCalendar($param['date'] , $param['target'], $param['plan'], '', 'actions', $id);
      //   // $this->battleplan_util->updateBattleplaCalendarId($id,$c_id);
      // }
      // echo 'true';
      // return;
    // }

  }
```

and here is the ionic code from where I'm trying to send the data

```
 var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: link,
            data: {
            token:token,
            plan: action,
            target: date,
            category: type,
            },
      });
      request.success(function (data) {
            debugger;
            $scope.tittle = data[0]['plan'];
            $scope.created =data[0]['date'];
            $scope.targetD = data[0]['target'];

            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: 'Data Sent And Received Successfully',
              template: data
            });
            alertPopup.then(function(res) {
              console.log('Data Sent And Received Successfully');
              $scope.checkStatus=false;
            });
      });
```

Please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong

**JSON **

Well I'm trying to encode this data into json. Here it is :

```
[23-May-2016 11:53:38 Asia/Karachi] Data is : Array
(
    [status] => false
    [type] => key
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_id] => MongoId Object
                        (
                            [$id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                        )

                    [plan] => Action
                    [target] => May 20, 2016
                    [status] => active
                    [type] => daily
                    [for] => MongoId Object
                        (
                            [$id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                        )

                    [category] => key
                    [date] => May 20, 2016
                    [starred] => 
                    [archived] => 
                    [visibility] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => MongoId Object
                                (
                                    [$id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The starred and archived have false in them but that doesn't shows up in the error log

Comment: Your json format is invalid. Post your json too.

Comment: yes get the json from network tab and post it here

Comment: Or check it on http://jsonlint.com

Comment: You echo `json_encode`d strings twice. Two `json_encode`d strings echo after each other is __not a valid__ json.

Comment: @u_mulder you were correct. Can you please post the answer so that I can accept it

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 3):

Modify your controller code like below.

```
public function addBattleplan(){

        $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
          $request = json_decode($postdata);
          $token = $request->token;
          $referrer = $request->referrer;
          // $type = $request->type;
          $param["plan"] = $request->plan;
          $param["date"] = $request->date;
          $param["category"] = $request->category;
          $token = $this->common_util->Decrypt('XXXXXXX',$token);


          $user = $this->User_Util->get_token($token);
          if (!$user) {
            echo false;
            return;
          }

          $user_id = $user[0]['user_id'];
          if ($request->target) {
              $param['target'] = date('M d, Y' , strtotime($request->target));
            } else {
              $param['target'] = '--';
            }
          // $param['date'] = $this->getToday();
          $param['date'] = date('M d, Y');
          $param['starred'] = FALSE;
          $param['archived'] = FALSE;
          $param["for"] = new MongoId($user_id);
          $param["type"] = "daily";

          error_log("The category is: ". $this->category);
          if ($request->category == "additional"){
            error_log("in additional");
            $this->addActionInBattleplan($param);
          }
          else{

            if($request->category == "key"){
              error_log("in key");
              $key_action = $this->Battleplan_Util->getKeyBattleplan($param["for"]);
              $key_action_count = count($key_action);
              if ($key_action_count == 0){
                error_log("adding");
                $this->addActionInBattleplan($param);
              }else{
                error_log("error found in key");
                $data["status"] = "false";
                $data["type"] = "key";
                $data["data"] = $key_action;
                error_log("Data is : ". print_r($data , true));
                // echo json_encode(array("status"=>"false","type"=>"key","data"=>$key_action[0]));
                $rawdata=json_encode(array("data" => $data));
              }
            }else{
              error_log("in important");
              $imp_action = $this->Battleplan_Util->getImportantBattleplan($param["for"]);
              $imp_actions_count = count($imp_action);
              if($imp_actions_count < 5){
                $this->addActionInBattleplan($param);
              }else{
                $rawdata= json_encode(array("status"=>"false" , "type"=> "important" , "data"=>$imp_action));
              }
            }
          }

          echo $rawdata;
          return;

      }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: did a small modification to the code that i posted earlier. please check on that. According to what I understood, I made the changes. skip if I'm wrong

Comment: Naa it changes a little bit of my logic but I have understood the problem as mentioned by @u_mulder in the comments above. Still thanks